# Warning: include(/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, phpexcel

Im having trouble including the `phpexcel` when im running it on my `local server` it's working but after i UP it in some hosting sites it's not working anymore. Can someone help me about this?

line 3

`include('/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');`

the error

`Warning: include(/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/disk11/2468402/www/censored/teacher/data/subject_model.php on line 3`

directories

- teacher

  - Classes

    - PHPExcel

      - IOFactory.php
  - data

    - subject_model.php

Comment: Remove the starting slash. Should be `include('../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');`

Comment: you just need to move one level up `../` not `/../`

Comment: `Warning: include(../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/disk11/2468402/www/censored/teacher/data/subject_model.php on line 3` still getting an error :3

Comment: Use `__DIR__` instead. `include(__DIR__ . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');`

Comment: So what folder did you put PHPExcel in?

Comment: Hey @panther it worked now. How can i mark your comment as a correct answer?

Comment: @nethkennnnn: comment isn't an answer so it can't be marked as a correct one. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__DIR__` instead.

```
include(__DIR__ . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
```